# i have a django data of time, i can't add it as time input field value

Tags: html, django, forms

I have a django model with a field of time. also I created a custom form with an input field so user can edit. If I parse this time as text input valur it show, but if it is time input and given the value time in it, the value is not shown

how to solve this?

Comment: can you make it more clearer

Answer (score 0):

You have to match the format of the `<input>`. It usually doesn't show the value because the format is not correct. [For reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time)

```html
<input type="time" value="23:00">
```

Here is an example in django.

```py
class TimeForm(forms.Form):
    time_input = forms.TimeField(widget=forms.TimeInput(attrs={"type": "time"}))
```

```py
def initialize_input(request):
    time_now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")
    some_data = {
        "time_input": time_now
    }

    context = {
        "form": TimeForm(some_data)
    } 

    return render(request, "template.html", contenxt)
```